# Rails only initialise an object if condition true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there an approach to conditionally prevent the creation of an object.

I have a `Person` class which `has_many :contacts`. If I try to initialize a `Contact` without providing an address, then the contact should not be created.

I can do this within a person object:

```
person.contacts << Contact.new(params[:contact]) if params[:address].present?
```

But can I do this within the Contact class? i.e. preventing the addition of a new Contact without the `if` condition above.

The reason for the question is that if I have contact fields on a form each with an address and their own contact_type in a hidden field, then the contact object would be created even if the address field is not populated.

**UPDATE**

Following further thoughts, the following are other options I have considered, but all have downsides:

1. remove from the params any contacts which do not include address:

Within the strong params method to iterate the params hash and remove any references to contacts without address `params[:person][:contacts_attributes].delete_if { |key, value| value[:address].blank? }`. This works, but obviously with a polymorphic model could be DRYer.

2. Create factory method within the `Person` and `Business` objects to define to assess the incoming request for a Person to be created and remove any contacts without address. I assume that this could be made DRY by abstracting into in a module, but this feels rather complex for this scenario.

At present option 1 above is what I am going to go with, but I'd be really interested if there is something that can be done in the `Contact` object.

Comment: why won't you just validate presence of address on create in Contact

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I do, but that causes my Person to be invalid, I just want no object, not an invalid object.

Comment: What do you mean that causes your Person to be invalid? Does a Person need at least one Contact?

Comment: @mckeed sorry, could have been clearer. A contact is created with a contact_type, but no address and added to the person.contacts. The contact is invalid, making the person invalid too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the answer lies in the following:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts, allow_destroy:true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[:address].blank? }
```

If I add the reject_if proc, then any submissions without an address seem to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the comment above that you **do** have a validation on the presence of the address field

Seems like there should be a better way to do this but, does this work for you?

```
new_contact = Contact.new(params)
person.contacts << new_contact if new_contact.valid?
```

**update:**

probably the right way to do this is like this

```
begin
  person.contacts.create! params
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Not sure that rescuing an exception rather that avoiding it is ideal and there may be other reasons for the record to be invalid which I would want to report back to the view. E.g. Address too long. I'm in two minds whether the model or the controller is the right place to prevent the create. I believe the Contacts model is best since the same rule applies whether it is person.contacts or business.contacts being created (in the case of a polymorphic relationship)

Answer (score 0):

It should probably be in the controller
In the create method 
`def create
@contact = Contact.new(params.require(:address).permit(:phone number, contact_type)
<end>`
This will not allow a contact to be created without an address but will allow a phone number and a contact type empty or not.

Comment: Thanks, you are probably correct that it should be in the controller, which obviously has the downside that it is not completely DRY on a polymorphic model. Your answer doesn't deal with update or integrated into Person.new(person_params).